# Using variable in transformations

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a requirement where a particular Kettle transformation (ktr) needs to be run multiple times.

This is the scenario:
A transformation has a table input which pulls user details belonging to a particular country.
I have almost 5 countries and this is saved in a separate table.
Can i make a variable and assign the country name to it and run the same transformation in a loop of five times, where every time the variable gets updated to the next country name.

I need the variable to be used in the table input query and in the column name also.

This is how i mentioned the variable in the table input.
[image: this is the method i used]

When i am giving the variable as value, in the output i am getting '${COUNTRY
}' instead of the value of the variable
[image: value is not shown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDI allows you to do multiple iteration using a variable. You need to use "copy rows to result" in kettel step. I have a blog written on this topic.

Blog Link : https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/

Please check if it helps you. :)